# Weird htop output? (screenshot)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, ubuntu, error, terminal

Not sure why this is happening or why the ./firefox command keeps repeating...

http://freedomsct2bsqtn.onion/fdwycmkknkayxmpanvvm/OTtAmNDT.png

$uname -a

Linux 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Answer (score 1):

These are threads, this is normal.

They're not multiple instances of `firefox` but instead a single instance that has multiple threads created for it. This may be more apparent if you press F5 to view it as a tree, you will see a main `firefox` instance with multiple children.

When a process wants to run tasks in parallel it will often create a new thread. The thread will run the task while in the background, each of these threads will appear as a "new" process while in fact they maintain (most) of the same process space as the initial process.

See: [Thread (Computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29).